# Risk-managing vanilla books (sell-side)

Tags: risk-management, greeks, option-strategies, gamma, vega

I am interested in learning more about how traders risk-manage books of vanilla options. I presume there should be a fairly standard list of facts. For the moment, the area of interest is FX, as things seem to be simpler there (no dividend adjustment). Are there good books/papers that present in a more intuitive, yet rigorous way the process of risk-managing such books?

Comment: Castagna's book, "FX Options and Smile Risk", has a chapter on "Risk Management Tools and Analysis". Might not be what you're after but of the FX vol books in my library (Clark, Castagna, Jewitt, Wystup), this is the only one with a chapter on risk management! Perhaps "Option Market Making" by Baird has some content relevant to your question?